# Gauss Hermite quadrature on finite interval

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, integration

I would like to approximate an Integral of the type

$I = \int_{x_l}^{x_u} f(x) w(x) dx$

where 
$w(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

and $f(x)$ is only defined on the Intervall $D = [x_l, \, x_u]$

I am interessted in both cases where D is bounded or unbounded at one side (e.g. $x_u \rightarrow \infty$). One example I consider is $f(x) = \sqrt{k + x}$, although I would prefer to consider $f(x)$ as a general, unknown function.

At the first glance it looks like usual Gauss-Hermite-Quadrature and can be approximated using $I \approx \sum w_i f(x_i)$, where Abscissas and Weights can easily be looked up. But the problem is, that I can't make sure that $x_i$ are within D. Is there a better way to numerically approximate the integral?

Thanks a lot in advance for answer!
Andy

Comment: If I understand your question (and I am not sure I do), that integral is not well-defined, let alone the part about computing it. If a function is only defined in a subinterval, you can't integrate it on a strictly larger one. Maybe you want $\int_{x_l}^{x_u} f(x)w(x)dx$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have edited the formula accordingly.